# VS Code - Cleanup list of interpreters

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

Over time I build up a lot of interpreters in my VS Code. Some of them are not working now, because I removed them, and also I removed the path in environmental variables to many of them, but those interpreters are still on the list. See picture.

The question is how to clean it up?? How do I remove those non-existent interpreters?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually, after we delete unnecessary environment folders in the project or source files, and then reload or restart VSCode, the corresponding kernel options will be deleted.

For multiple "`Python: 3`" (different paths) that appear in the options, we have submitted this problem, and we expect it to be resolved.

Github link: [The Jupyter kernel in VSCode has duplicate options.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4074).

Comment: Removing duplicate entries does not address cleaning up the list of entries that may be obsolete